# squarespace collections - loop through index pages

Tags: squarespace

I'm new to squarespace and unfamiliar with how it works, however i have searched and trawled through the documentation and related material and i cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the below. I apologise if my structure or wording is in someway not clear or appropriate.

I thank you all in advance.

**Question:**

I have two index's with pages under both, each page has a thumbnail. I have created a collection named 'locations' and i wish to somehow create a .item file for this collection to gather page thumbnails for the two index's so i can output this data via summary - carousel.

In short, i need a method to loop through each page under an index and grab the thumbnail and link associated with each item.

**Desired outcome:**

To be able to add a summary - carousel which outputs thumbnail images /associated links of pages under two predefined index's.

**Resources:**

```
location.conf:
{
  "title" : "Locations Collection",
  "ordering" : "chronological",
  "addText" : "Add Post",
  "acceptTypes": ["text"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see your JSON output in order to think what will be the logic for the loop.

Usually the loop index logic is

```
{.section collection}
   {.repeated section collections}
    // rest of JSON logic in here
   {.end}
{.end}
```

But you have to review your page pretty-json in order to code it to your needs.